# How can I change the Corner Radius property of a Segmented Controller in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm struggling a lot trying to change the Corner Radius of a customized Segmented Controller. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Blessings

```
  lazy var mainSegment: UISegmentedControl = {
   let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.selectedSegmentTintColor = .orange
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.backgroundColor = .white
    sc.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
    sc.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
    sc.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    sc.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
    sc.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    sc.clipsToBounds = true
    sc.layer.masksToBounds = true
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentChanges), for: .valueChanged)

    return sc
}()
```

Comment: It works for me, pasting your code in a playground.  What does it look like for you?

Comment: Hello, It actually works, but the corner radius is not equal to the height's segmented controller divided by 2, which would make it totally rounded. And the only corner radius that we see it's the default value. Do you know how to access the radius corner property in iOS 13?